# sqlite char, ascii function

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there any work around in sqlite to cover for the lack of "char()" and "ascii()" function ?

For example:

```
char(97) => 'a'
ascii('a') => 97
```

Comment: Well, SQLite isn't really intended for performing massive amounts of processing after insertion of data, so why not do this computation in your calling code? (In C, C#, Java, C++, and many others, this is ridiculously easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose, if you really wanted to, you could create a "ASCII Table" Table of values with a `ASCIICHAR` column, and a `ASCIICODE` column, and populate it with the ASCII table. Then your lookups could be performed in queries / subqueries:

```
SELECT ASCIICHAR FROM ASCIITABLE WHERE ASCIICODE = 97;
```

Really though, Richard J. Ross III's comment is on the money - if you are using SQLite, you are probably accessing it through your calling code, couldn't the computation be done there?

Answer (score 23):

I know this is too late but:

```
SELECT unicode('a') --ascii('a')
SELECT char(97)     --char(97)
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This should be the answer. It most directly solves OP's question. And mine, too!

Answer (score 3):

Since the time this question was written, SQLite has evidently added a `CHAR()` function:

```
SELECT CHAR(97) -- Result is 'a'
```

However, the closest I've gotten in the other direction is with the `HEX()` function:

```
SELECT HEX('a') -- Result is 61 (hexadecimal, is equal to 97 decimal)
```

Obtaining a decimal `ASCII` character value seems like it'd require some convoluted work...

Comment: In which version of SQLite has it been added?

Answer (score 0):

Although conversion is not likely, sqlite does recognize ASCII in this query:

```
select * from segments where substr(name, 1, 1) < 'A' or substr(name, 1, 1) > 'Z' and substr(name, 1, 1) < 'a';
```

Possible results: 0-9 and all ASCII < 'a'

Answer (score 0):

It would be trivial to implement sqlite3 user functions ascii() and char() that perform the conversions in C or through another language wrapper that supports sqlite3 user functions (e.g. in python).

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own version of ascii based on the sqlite extension library that is on this site: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Extension-functions-for-SQLite-in-C-for-free-td18942.html

I have modified this code to add functions, not specifically yours though. It should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions use cast(X'61' as text) instead of char(97). 61 is the hexadecimal prepresentation of 97.