# WHERE condition is true but not all rows are returned? (SQLite db)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, conditional-statements, where-clause

When I try to use `WHERE word = "a"` there is only 1 row returned when in fact there are 2 rows with the word "a". As you can see in the second picture there is also another "a" with the id = 1. How can I query both of them?

[Only 1 row is returned with `WHERE word = "a"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXJOs.png)

[There are actually 2 rows with for the word "a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkW0U.png)

UPDATE: They actually have different length,
[one 1 and the other 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIWUi.png)

Comment: Perhaps there are spaces after the `a` in the other row?

Comment: What if you use like "%a%", and what does length(word) show?

Comment: They actually have different length, now how can I query both of them :(

Comment: Update the table to remove the trailing spaces: `UPDATE av SET word = TRIM(word)`

Comment: @forpas I tried but the the length still stayed 2.

Comment: Your data probably contains other non-printable characters such as tab or return etc; does `like "%a%" find exactly the two rows expected?

Comment: @Stu It does but it will also return other different rows that matches "%a%". I need a way to find the exact "a".

Comment: Look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604766/sqlite-char-ascii-function) then for how to identify other characters that you need to *replace*